# Concatenate variable to constant string in generating command name

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to pass argument in a shell script. This is what i have done:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$1
echo $name

cd folder

/users9/test/test1/ggandhi/wmd/latest/test/resources/ + name
```

I want to append the value of `name` after the resources directory. Does anyone know how would I do it?

Comment: what does `$name` denote? Is it a script?

Comment: @Fazlin name is just a variable with my value which i want to pass to /users9/test/test1/ggandhi/wmd/latest/test/resources/ + name.

Comment: What do you mean by the `+`?  You can't use a directory path as a command.

Comment: @Kusalananda + here just to show you guys what i want to do. I want to pass my name value at the end of the resources. Any way to do that?

Comment: So your `+` denotes string concatenation. You might want to mention that in your question; it's not entirely obvious.

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with *passing* arguments, but rather about *concatenating* strings.

Comment: `echo "$name"`, by the way, as opposed to just `echo $name`. The two commands may *look* the same -- but if, for instance, `name='hello * world'` the behavior between the two would be very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$name` corresponds to a command (script or binary) in that folder, the last line of your script should read like

```
/users9/test/test1/ggandhi/wmd/latest/test/resources/"$name"
```

This will execute the command given by `$name` which resides inside the folder `/users9/test/test1/ggandhi/wmd/latest/test/resources`.

Also, put double quotes around `$1` when you assign it to `name`:

```
name="$1"
```

Comment: I suggest using double quotes in case `$name` contains any funny characters.

Comment: @KeithThompson It's late, I'm getting sloppy. Thanks.

Comment: The quotes aren't strictly needed on the assignment -- though it's better to use them than not when uncertain. The expansion, on the other hand, they're certainly called for in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy When I'm not this tired, I usually double quote all user-supplied data, regardless of whether it's actually needed or not.